# How to add custom css responsive in Avada WP Theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website with avada wprdpress theme. I´ve added a custom css in "Custom CSS" from theme options. This working fine for desktops, but didn´t work for mobile resolutions.

Example:

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 640px){
    .fusion-alignleft{
        max-width: 80%;
        float:left;
    }
    .fusion-alignright{
        max-width: 20%;
        float:right;
    }
    .fusion-contact-info {
        padding: 1em 0px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    .fusion-body .fusion-mobile-menu-design-modern .fusion-secondary-header .fusion-alignright{
        text-align: right;
    }
}
```

How to add responsive styles in avada wordpress theme options?

Comment: try using `@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px)`

Comment: Thank you Gaurav Aggarwal !!! Is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS media there's a difference between device-width and width resolution.  You can read more on this here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

That said, try this...

```
@media all and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
.fusion-alignleft {
    max-width: 80%;
    float:left;
}
.fusion-alignright {
    max-width: 20%;
    float:right;
}
.fusion-contact-info {
    padding: 1em 0px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.fusion-body .fusion-mobile-menu-design-modern .fusion-secondary-header .fusion-alignright {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```